# Can someone verify my work for finding the following closures?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory, computer-science, relations

This is the problem I am currently working on

12. Let R be the relation on the set {0, 1, 2, 3} containing the ordered pair (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,2), and (3,0). Find the 
    a.reflexive closure of R.
    b.symmetric closure of R.
    c.The transitive closure of R.

Here are my answers 
a.The reflexive closure of R is the relation containing  the ordered pairs (0,0), (0,1), (1, 1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,2), (3,0), (3,3)
b.The symmetric closure of R is the relation containing the ordered pairs (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (3,0)
c.The transitive closure of R is the relation containing the ordered pairs (0, 1), (0,2), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2)

Does everything look good? Did I miss any ordered pairs?

Comment: I think you missed at least one. For transitive closure you have to keep going until your relation is transitive.

Comment: which one did i miss for transitive? I did keep going.

Comment: You have (0,2) and (2,0)...

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you !

Comment: For the symmetric closure, you forgot $(2,0)$ - but it's already in the original relation, so you didn't really made a "mistake".